# How can I bind an HTML hidden field with a property in Blazor (server side)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to bind a **HTML hidden field** with a property of an object.
Here is my code that I'm trying to execute:

```
<!--ForeignKeyOptions-->
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="foreignkeyoptions"
           class="input-group input-group-static">
        ForeignKeyOptions
    </label>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        @foreach (Role? role in roleRepository
                                    .GetAll(CancellationToken.None))
        {
            <button type="button" 
                class="btn bg-gradient-primary">
                @role?.Name
            </button>
            <input type="hidden" 
                id="foreignkeyoptions"
                @bind="Test.ForeignKeyOptions" />
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to put the attribute **value** as `value="role.RoleId"` but Visual Studio tells me that the value attribute can't be used because **@bind** is using it. How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the purpose of hidden values? Because on BlazorServer you have the context, don't need to hide a value inside of html... Can you also show the non-working piece of code?

Comment: Hi @Alamakanambra That is the HTML code that is not working, and how can I save data in the object Test using your way using "context"? What is the meaning of that way? Thanks

Comment: Binding is probably not needed. 
value="@role.RoleId" should do the job. 
(Be careful, in a loop  id="foreignkeyoptions" won’t be unique.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have used `@bind="Test.ForeignKeyOptions"` in the input.
Generally, if you want to bind the value you should use `@bind-value="@role.RoleId"`.

`@bind` is an override of `@bind-value` with the event set to "onchange". Which means:
`@bind=xxx"`
equals to
`@bind-value="xxx" @bind-value:event="onchange"`
So please check if you want to bind "Test.ForeignKeyOptions"or "@role.RoleId" or both.

Comment: Cool sir, Im going to probe what you put, thanks!